# java web service get parameter while using post method

Tags: java, web, service

I did a java rest web service using GET method.The web service works fine with GET method.But when i try it with POST method it doesn't display anything.
Below is my simple code to test it with POST method.
Please anyone help me in solving this issue.

```
@Path("/post")
public class Testpost {

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    public String POST(@QueryParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "POST:hELLO: "+msg;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public String POST(@QueryParam("param") String msg) {
```

There will be no `@QueryParam` for POST. It is only for GET.

For POST, you should use `@RequestParam`

Comment: Can you please put that annotation in my method and show.It would be very helpful.

Comment: The post method worked with @QueryParam only on SoapUI.Thank u for at least going through my question and providing me with some way to fix the problem.